# Launching Instances in Default VPC Produces Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to just launch webservers into my webservers security group, but I get this:

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-someami --count 2 --instance-type m3.medium --key-name some_key --security-groups Webservers

A client error (InvalidParameterCombination) occurred when calling the RunInstances operation: VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch
```

What gives? I just want to launch boxes into my default VPC. I don't want to specify a subnet, but even if I do, I can no longer specify my security group. I'm new to EC2, and would rather not worry about doing non-default things with my VPC until I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Security Groups are linked to specific VPCs.**

Check whether your Security Group is associated to a VPC that is different to the one in which you are launching the Amazon EC2 Instance (in this case, different to the Default VPC).

If so, create a new Security Group in the Default VPC and use that when launching the instances.

If you are using **EC2-Classic** (not VPC), note the following from the [AWS CLI documentation on `run-instances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-RunInstances.html):

> --security-groups (list)
>
> [EC2-Classic, default VPC] One or more security group names. For a nondefault VPC, you must use security group IDs instead.

So, try using `--security-group-ids` with an ID.

Comment: My account is older, so my default is no VPC. I just want to launch my instances into the same vpc my security group is setup for.

Comment: If your account is old, you probably have EC2 Classic available.  The command you gave does not specify a subnet ID, so your instance will start in EC2 Classic.  As John explained, you can not mix and match VPC security groups and EC2 Classic security groups.  Solution : start your instance in a VPC using the --subnet-id option.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch

means that you are trying to launch the instance outside the [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). Please note that a security group is associated with an instance. In other words, there is a relationship between Security Group and Subnets that is both linked to a VPC.

This is the most common problem when you are switching to different instance (such as t2.micro) and not specifying a `vpc_ic` and `subnet_id`, example for packer:

```
"vpc_id": "vpc-62086907",
"subnet_id": "subnet-01451564",
```

You should check the settings of your instance such as:

- parameters for the instance creation process,
- you need to supply the subnet ID within which to launch the instances 
  for VPC ([`subnet_id`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#subnet_id) for Packer/Vagrant, or vpc_subnet_id for Ansible),
- when configuring AWS VPC, make sure to use only the Subnet ID and the Group IDs,
- also double check whether you may be on the older version of AWS, so update the template to build a VPC as well.

Related:

- [Problems building a CentOS AWS AMI with Packer](http://blog.awolski.com/building-an-aws-ami-with-packer/)
- [Your VPC and Subnets - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html)